# Calling method Java

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, boolean

Im having difficulty understanding what exactly I should pass my third method in the main class with. Im really just sort of lost at this point. Any help would be awesome. Here is my code that I have written:

Also, here are the directions for boolean method called "getOrder":

Write a method called getOrder that takes an ArrayList of Strings as a parameter (the products ArrayList) and returns a boolean.
In the method body, prompt the user to enter a product name (a String), then check whether the product name exists in the ArrayList of strings.
If it exists, return true, otherwise return false.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Call your methods here
    bannerPrinter();
    productBuilder();
    getOrder(??); -----------------------------Confused as to what to pass this method with

}

// Write your methods below here

public static boolean getOrder(ArrayList<String> products) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a product name: ");
    String productName = in.nextLine();
    if (products.contains(productName)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }       
}

public static ArrayList<String> productBuilder() {
    ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
    products.add("Desktop");
    products.add("Phone");
    products.add("TV");
    products.add("Speaker");
    products.add("Laptop");

    return products;

}
public static void bannerPrinter() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println("****** Welcome to my eCommerce app! ******");
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass an `ArrayList<String>`. Looking at your code, you build one with `productBuilder()` which is otherwise unused. So:

```
ArrayList<String> products = productBuilder();
getOrder(products);
```

or

```
getOrder(productBuilder());
```

---

BTW, the following code:

```
if (products.contains(productName)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

is more easily written as

```
return products.contains(productName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You would just pass an `ArrayList`. Like this:

```
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("Phone");
lst.add("Laptop");
getOrder(lst);
```

You would fill your `ArrayList` first of course and then pass it.